# Existence of Randomized polynomial time algorithm and some arithmetic analog of $ACC^0$ circuits for Factoring of primitive polynomials before LLL?

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, computational-complexity, big-picture, computational-number-theory

Before LLL came along in $1982$ there was no deterministic polynomial (in degree and number of bits in coefficients) way to factor square free primitive polynomials in $\Bbb Z[x]$.

However was there a probabilistic polynomial (in degree and number of bits in coefficients) way to factor square free primitive polynomials in $\Bbb Z[x]$? Is there a reference?

---

The reason for the query is following. The LLL algorithm is highly iterative and in circuit complexity parlance seems to be polynomial size in $O(\log n)$ depth .  So I am wondering if there was a randomized or deterministic algorithm which can factor at least a fraction of primitive polynomials in $\Bbb Z[x]$ and that which would still be in $O(1)$ depth and polynomial size.

Comment: You might check (old editions of) _The Art Of Computer Programming_ vol. 2; that discusses polynomial factorization and the first couple of editions predate LLL. I don't know that they're _explicitly_ probabilistic polynomial (in particular, because the main algorithm works over $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})[x]$ for many $p$ and uses the CRT to staple results together, and as the book notes there are polynomials for which this approach is doomed to failure) but the references therein are probably your best bet.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki it is not well covered in the book by Knuth http://aleteya.cs.buap.mx/~jlavalle/papers/books_on_line/Addison.Wesley.Donald.E.Knuth.The.Art.of.Computer.Programming.Volume.2.pdf

Answer (score 3):

The Zassenhaus algorithm (see [the Wikipedia article on factoring](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Factorization_of_polynomials)) Is polynomial, except for the exponential dependence on the number of irreducible factors of the polynomial. However, the expected number of irreducible factors is $O(1)$ (see [this nice UChicago REU](http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2015/REUPapers/AlegreJuarezPajela.pdf) by Alegra Juarez), so Zassenhaus is expected polynomial time. The worst case is horrible, though, and so the Novocin-van Hoeij algorithm (see Novocin's [very nice description](http://andy.novocin.com/pro/paris.pdf)) cleverly circumvents the problems.

Comment: So there was no randomized algorithm?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: where does it say $O(1)$? I do not see it. It is interesting. This is a randomized poly algorithm then right?

Comment: Also it looks like Zassenhaus' algorithm is non-iterative and can be implemented in constant depth right? (that is all the work that needs to be done in Hensel lifting can be done in parallel and all the work that needs to be done for matching factors can be done in parallel right. not much sequentiality like LLL iterative basis search right?).

Comment: Looks like even Hensel lifting can be done in one step in Zassenhaus algorithm (algorithm 15.10 $m^2$b can be replaced by $m^l$ by remarks in theorem 2 page 14 in http://www.mmrc.iss.ac.cn/~lzhi/Course/mchapter15.ps) and does not have to proceed $p^2\rightarrow p^4\rightarrow\dots$ correct?

Comment: If you read the REU carefully, you will see the $O(1).$

Comment: which section to focus?

Comment: Also can hensel lifting be done in one step instead of $k$ steps for $p^k$ mod?

Comment: @AJ the one on the number of factors. Actually, the expectation is smaller than $2.$

Comment: any knowledge about Hensel lifting complexity?

Comment: @AJ not sure, I haven't thought about it.